# BizTalk Custom Pipeline component in GAC not updating

Tags: biztalk, gac, biztalk-2013, custom-pipeline-component

I've recently started following [this method for Pipeline Component Development](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26404.biztalk-deploying-custom-pipeline-components-in-biztalk-server-2006-and-higher.aspx) and it's been working great for the development part of things. It even worked nicely for the first deploy of the components/pipelines.

However, the problem is now, when I deploy changes to the pipeline component DLLs, I cannot get them to update.

I follow the post as far as adding the assemblies to the GAC. I then Export the MSI containing my assemblies from BizTalk and import, with "Overwrite" option. I restart hosts instances, restart IIS (since my isolated host is using the component) but the changes I've made to the dll are not happening on the (in this case) staging server.

I've checked the MSIL folder and the folders and dlls are indeed getting updated date-modified, but my changes are not happening when I send messages through.

Is there a step I'm missing? Do I have to increase version numbers on the components themselves? I've increased versions and redeployed the pipelines that reference the components, and even that doesn't kick off the changes.

Answer (score 1):

I found my issue. In my development environment, I had to:

- right-click on the resources in `<myApplication>/Resources`
- choose 'Modify' and then press the
- 'Refresh' button.
- navigate to the GAC directory where the dll for the custom pipeline is installed `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\<myComponent>\v4.0_<myVersion>__<myPublickey>`
- restart host instances (unsure if this is totally necessary)

THEN I could export the dll and import it on the destination server (with `Overwrite Resources` checked). Without that Refresh, the dll changes were not being recognized on the destination server. Hopefully this save someone some time someday.

Comment: Yes, the MSI export always comes from the BizTalk database and not the GAC, which is why it is a dangerous thing to only GAC a DLL and not also import it into the BizTalk database, either by the Refresh as above or Importing a MSI that has it in it.   You might want to consider adding a BTTask step to your post build step to AddResource https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561819.aspx to import and GAC at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to export the assembly into an msi to install it. Adding it, or updating it, in the resources area will do the same thing as the import. We use this method regularly.

I usually **do** increment the version number because it helps ensure the code I expect to run is being run. It also makes rolling back to a previous version simple in case of a production issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is also worth checking in **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64** and **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32** to see if there are any references to the old version of same DLL.

We had a similar issue and after days of debugging we ended up finding an old reference in the other two GAC folders.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34753178)